# Delete record from database symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony, entity

I just created an action that delete a record of an entity from my db.
The action is:

```
public function eliminaricettaAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $ricetta = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Ricette')->find($id);
        $em->remove($ricetta);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render('adminarea/gestionericette.html.twig', array(
                    'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/..'),
        ));
    }
```

And the error I get is:

> Warning: unlink(): No such file or directory

So I think the problem is in the entity it self, in particular in this peace of code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function removeImage()
{
    unlink($this->getFullImagePath());
    rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to remove the item from the database AND remove the file from the filesystem?

Comment: I want to delete a record that contains a file field, that in this case is an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to delete a file that does not exist.

Before attempting to delete files, you should make sure they exist. Confirm that you actually get a file path back from `$this->getFullImagePath()`, and that the file at the path exists by using [file_exists()](http://php.net/file_exists).

You could implement it like this:

```
public function removeImage()
{
    if($file = $this->getFullImagePath() && file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
        rmdir($this->getUploadRootDir());
    }
}
```

Ideally, you would also check that `$this->getUploadRootDir()` returns a value and that the directory exists and is not empty before attempting to remove it; but you might also consider whether or not it's actually necessary to remove the `uploadRootDir` each time a file is deleted. (Whether you should or not is a separate question entirely.)

Comment: The entity has a file field, but in this case is empty. So it doesn't exist and I get the error?

Comment: Yes. `unlink('')` still attempts to delete a file, and you get the error because a file with an empty name doesn't exist.

Comment: So to solve the problem, in the function removeImage(), if I put the unlink and the rmdir in an if construct like : if(file_exist($image)), it will work?

Comment: Yes; I've updated the answer with one way of doing that.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But now the error is: Notice: Undefined variable: image

Comment: Well, you can't just use a variable without putting something into it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check that the file exists, and [@jbafford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34813484/1697192) is good about this.

But next you must check that the `uploadRootDir` is not empty because you can't remove a directory that is not empty.

```php
$scannedDir = $this->getUploadRootDir();
if (is_dir($scannedDir)) {
    $entries = scandir($entries);
    if (count($entries) === 2) {
        // When you have 2 entries it means you have "." and ".."
        rmdir($scannedDir);
    } else {
        // Directory is not empty, so take care about this.
    }
} else {
    // Directory does not exist so you may throw an exception or do something else.
}
```